# Not getting enough attention for my question

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question

I asked this question in Stack Overflow

[Declare field outside/inside method : Sonar Singular Field Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703134/declare-field-outside-inside-method-sonar-singular-field-rule)

1. Why am I not getting enough answers?
2. Is it because my reputation is low?
3. Is it because the question is tough? It doesn't look that difficult.

What is the reason and how to get more answers?

Comment: Are you dissatisfied with the answer you got? How many were you expecting?

Comment: At least 5 so that I can decide who deserve to get points. And also to get more idea about it. There is only 1 for now. So I simply vote it up.  :)

Comment: You have unreasonable expectations, in my opinion. Be satisfied if you have an answer that fulfills your needs. If I see that an existing user has already covered the ground that I wanted to cover, I won't submit an answer.

Comment: I agree with you. :) But if answer is less, it is hard to decide the right answer.  :)

Comment: i think there are only  some user who using sonar ....so please Waite

Comment: @Mawia - Please don't be angry because [voting is different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: @NullPointer I think you are right. And may be, I shouldn't even include that Sonar tag at all. It might cause others to ignore the question.

Comment: This is bad. My point keeps on going down. I am going to delete this question. One more down, then I delete.

Comment: @Mawia Reputation on Meta is basically meaningless. You didn't do anything wrong; people are simply downvoting to express disagreement with the central premise of your question (that you should get more answers). There is nothing fundamentally wrong with asking this question, so don't worry about the downvotes.

Comment: People on Meta don't like rant and whining and this is exactly what you did here in your question.

Comment: @Mawia also deleting questions because of downvotes to save your rep is an extremely bad habit to get into.  This is not as likely to happen on Meta, but over on SO, deleted questions (especially downvoted questions) are a major factor in this: [What can I do when getting “Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/182513).  So please don't delete for the sake of saving your rep.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It wasn't all *that* ranty or whiny, really. The OP (politely) asked how they could get more answers, were told getting a single answer is good enough, and agreed.

Comment: @Mawia and to address your question here, you just asked this question less than 24 hours ago.  Don't be in such a rush to accept anything.  Nothing says you have to accept an answer now or even this week.  You can wait and see if someone comes in later with a better answer.  If you accept an answer now, your chances of getting more answers later are lower.

Comment: Great idea @psubsee2003.

Comment: @Asad never said it wasn't polite. But still, one can't expect to get answers instantly. As I see it, he feels like people on Stack Overflow owe him or work for him. Well, they don't.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ooops! you got me wrong. I know it's not easy to give  answers. It takes time and brain. I myself wasted a lot of my time to give answers and sometimes got nothing from it.

Comment: @Mawia fair enough, maybe language misunderstanding. Using the word "attention" instead of "answers" might have helped people like myself understand you better.

Comment: Rather than wait for a number of answers then having a beauty parade, which is what it sounds like you're doing when you say you want at least 5 answers, why not test the one you have now to see if its a solution or not? If it is a full solution then you don't need more answers. If it doesn't work for you or only works partially then reporting back the results of that test might inspire more answers.

Comment: @RobM  My apologies if it sounds greedy. But my question was not for a solution. It was for explanation.

Comment: @mawia - fair point (not that I interpreted it as greed) but my comment still stands, I think. Only one reply can still be the One True Explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why am I not getting enough answers?

You should wait for some times. At least 1 day or 2. If you are still not getting enough attention/reply you can start [a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties).

> Is it because my reputation is low?

No. Low reputation does'n matter for that because no one look at your reputation (IMO) while reading a question.

> Is it because the question is tough? It doesn't look that difficult.

I don't know if the question is tough or not. But I know that people *love* to answer tough questions.

Between, try to improve the quality of your question and also try to make it more clear.

Comment: I think people definitely look at the rep, more times than not you can tell if the person has 1 rep by the quality of the question they ask. That being said I totally agree with your other two points

Answer (score 3):

From reading your question I'd say it's because it's a difficult question to understand. Not impossible, but it takes a bit of effort on the readers part to interpret what information you want to know. That in itself can put potential answerers off. Let me explain:

In your question you refer often to Sonar, and talk about a "rule violation". Yet your question appears to be about run-time optimisation - specifically whether or not there is a difference in execution time between

```
public class MyClass{

   MyType object;   

   public void myMethod(){
         object= aMethod(arg);  //Returns instance for the class MyType 
   }

}
```

and

```
public class MyClass{  

   public void myMethod(){
         MyType object= aMethod(arg);  //Returns instance for the class MyType 
   }

}
```

With a small follow-up question along the lines of "Sonar is telling me to do it the second way, why?"

Or at least that's what it reads to me like you're asking. But I cannot be sure because you don't even state what you're comparing your code to, you just saying that "Sonar is telling me to" etc etc. That's not a clear way to phrase your question.